# Mock Stored procedures with Spring Boot and HSQLDB

Tags: spring-boot, stored-procedures, hsqldb

I am working on a Spring Boot project with HSQLDB as in-memory database for my tests. 
The reason why I decided to use HSQLDB over h2 is that my datasource is quite old and contains a lot of queries with multiple OUT parameters that H2 cannot handle

While I am able to run using JPA queries with multiple OUT parameters on HSQL, I need now to Mock some of the stored procedures.

In H2 is possible as you can see for instance [here](https://medium.com/@callkalpa/user-defined-functions-and-stored-procedures-with-h2-database-a1cbfa510559). Is it possible to mock stored procedures on HSQLDB? So far I could find only some really old articles (2011) and nothing in the HSQLDB documentation itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB supports stored procedures with OUT parameters. You can write the procedure in SQL or Java. An example from the documentation below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE new_customer(OUT newid INT, IN firstname VARCHAR(50), IN lastname VARCHAR(50), IN address VARCHAR(100))
   MODIFIES SQL DATA
   BEGIN ATOMIC
     DECLARE temp_id INTEGER;
     INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (DEFAULT, firstname, lastname, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
     SET temp_id = IDENTITY();
     INSERT INTO ADDRESSES VALUES (DEFAULT, temp_id, address);
     SET newid = temp_id;
   END
```

You can find the above example, as well as an example written in Java in the Guide. http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation url provided by @fredt, I found [this example](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_jrt_procedures) that does the job for me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_customer(IN id INT, OUT firstname VARCHAR(50), OUT lastname VARCHAR(50)) 
READS SQL DATA    
LANGUAGE JAVA    
EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:org.hsqldb.test.Test01.getCustomerProcedure' 

public static void getCustomerProcedure(int id, String[] firstn, String[] lastn) throws java.sql.SQLException { 
firstn[0] = somevalue; // parameter out value is assigned 
lastn[0] = somevalue; // parameter out value is assigned
 }
```